# Sorting a list of tuples on multiple keys

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort a list of tuples where the tuples are of type `(a, b)` where `a` and `b` are integers. The key for sorting the list should be the difference between `a` and `b` i.e `a - b` and to break the ties, it should sort on `a`, both in descending order.

I tried using this:

```
def sort(list):
        scores = sorted(list, key=lambda list: list[0], reverse=True)
        scores = sorted(list, key=lambda list: (a - b), reverse=True)
```

But this seems to sort on the difference and reorder the elements sorted on the first element of the tuple.

For example:

**The input:**

```
[(75, 10),  (88, 4), (93, 9), (80, 5), (94, 10)]
```

**The expected output:**

```
[(94, 10), (93, 9), (88, 4), (80, 5), (75, 10)]
```

**The obtained output:**

```
[(93, 9), (88, 4), (94, 10), (80, 5), (75, 10)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort on a compound key:

```
>>> def sort(list):
...     return sorted(list, key=(lambda (a, b): ((a - b), a)), reverse=True)
... 
>>> sort([(75, 10),  (88, 4), (93, 9), (80, 5), (94, 10)])
[(94, 10), (93, 9), (88, 4), (80, 5), (75, 10)]
```

See the [Python Wiki Sorting Howto](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) for some nice tips.

Answer (score 1):

```
list_sorted = sorted(list, key = lambda x: (x[0]-x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)
```

The `lambda` for `key` can return tuples whose order can indicate the sort priorities.

Answer (score 1):

To get the ordering you are looking for, sort using a compound key:

```
def sort(l):
    scores = sorted(l, key=lambda(e): (e[0] - e[1], e[0]), reverse=True)
```

This will yield:

```
scores = [(94, 10), (93, 9), (88, 4), (80, 5), (75, 10)]
```

**N.B:** [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) is a keyword and should not be used as a variable name.

Comment: Incorrect. The difference is supposed to be the first criteria.   Add tuple `(95, 94)` to the list and you will see it sorted incorrectly.  Additionally, you have the terms in the difference reversed.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Thanks, have fixed. Normally I'd delete such an answer but other answers miss the danger of using `list` as an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

The key lambda wants one input value (a tuple is OK)

```
sorted(data, key=lambda (a, b): (a-b, a), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't break the ties :/. I got the ordering without using anything complicated... here:

```
def sort(list):
    scores = sorted(list, key=lambda a: a[0], reverse=True)

    return scores

print sort([(75, 10),  (88, 4), (93, 9), (80, 5), (93, 11), (94, 10)])
```

Console:

```
[(94, 10), (93, 9), (93, 11), (88, 4), (80, 5), (75, 10)]
```

When I sort on differences, a-b, this is the result:

```
def sort(list):

    scores = sorted(list, key=lambda a: a[0], reverse=True)
    scores = sorted(list, key=lambda a: a[0]-a[1], reverse=True)

    return scores

print sort([(75, 10),  (88, 4), (93, 9), (80, 5), (93, 11), (94, 10)])
```

Console:

```
[(88, 4), (93, 9), (94, 10), (93, 11), (80, 5), (75, 10)]
```

Comment: I want to sort the list on the difference of the elemental tuples. It works for this input case but not in general.

Comment: Yes I noticed. I've been trying with a slightly different input:
[(75, 10),  (88, 4), (93, 9), (80, 5), (93, 11), (94, 10)]. Are you sure about your expected input? Because when I sort of differences a-b, the output is very different.

Comment: Yes, hope you saw it is descending order.